# If you have a reaction that causes Prone, can you cause a creature using Stand to be Prone again?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, reactions, prone

In a recent bout with lesser deaths, we noticed some particulars about [Move Actions that Trigger Reactions](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=446). Particularly:

> If you use a move action but don’t move out of a square, the trigger instead happens at the end of that action or ability.

To me, this seems like causing Prone again is viable because the target was no longer Prone when the Reaction is actually activated (although you would not be targeting Prone statistics if that's relevant). Is that correct or is there more information about it that I'm missing?

There aren't a lot of such abilities yet, but they do exist such as [Soulbound Ruins](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=475)' Impede which can force a Reflex Save against becoming Prone in response to a Move action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Yes

You've quoted the relevant rule, and standing up would count as a move action that doesn't move the character out of the square.

So [Standing](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=86) would trigger the reaction, but the trigger would happen after completing the Stand when the character is likely no longer prone. On a failed save against Impede, the character would go back to being prone.